# TreeView navigation and MainContent In ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview

Been trying to use the Treeview as navigation.
I made use of the Site Master. The treeview is by the left side and it is embedded in a  and also Scrollable. The MainContent is by the right side and it is enclosed in the  tag as well.

I do not want the treeview to move along with the page when the page is scrolled up or down. And also the Maincontent should also be within the div tag. Below is the code used.

```
<div class="container body-content">
<div class="row">
   <hr />
   <div class="col-md-2" style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:scroll; height:700px; position:fixed;">
      <p style="font-size:20px; color:blue;"> Menu Navigation</p>
      <asp:TreeView ID="TV_Navigation" runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" NodeIndent="10" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
         <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#DD5555" />
         <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
            NodeSpacing="2px" VerticalPadding="0px"></NodeStyle>
         <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
         <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px"
            ForeColor="#DD5555" />
      </asp:TreeView>
      <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" /         
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8" style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:scroll; height:700px; position:fixed; width:80%;">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider formatting your code.  In my experience, well-formatted code and good instructions of the problem leads to more replies/answers.  Try: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: This may help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/